# Basic Php Question

Tags: php, html, css

How would I make the font inside a php tag blue.

```
<?php $colors = array(blue); ?>
<hr />

<br />
<?php echo $colors [0] ; ?>
```

The array is very simple but I do not know how to change to font color.  The output will echo "blue" it is in black font.  However,  I am going to have the array with several different colors (6). I figured if I seen an example that I would understand it.  That is the reason I only provided one example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php doesn't affect style, but you could always print it inside a css statement, something like

```
<p style="color:<?php echo $colors[0];?>">colored text here</p>
```

Edit: better yet, print a class name so you could keep a separated style sheet and not use inline style, like `class="<?php echo $classblue;?>"`

Comment: Thanks - It took a while for it to sink in but I understood it after I played around with it.

Answer (score 4):

You can't set the colour of anything inside a PHP tag. It is executable code.

When the code is executed, then it may output something that could have a colour. This is usually HTML.

To make something blue in HTML:

1. Decide *why* it should be blue
2. Generate appropriate [semantic HTML](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/15-marking-up-textual-content-in-html/) to describe that reason
3. Write [CSS](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/27-css-basics/) with a [selector](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/) that matches that semantic HTML and `color: blue;` in the rule-set.

Answer (score 0):

Also you have to use HTML,

```
<span style="color: <?php echo $colors[0]; ?>">Hello</span>
```

Comment: `<font>`? Next year is the 15th anniversary of its deprecation!

Comment: You should refrain from using the `<font>` attribute, divide structure from presentation

Comment: The level of the question strongly suggests that *good* examples are needed so that bad habits are not encouraged.